# NERDTreeToggle opens in Windows/system32

Tags: windows, vim, nerdtree

I've added the following useful settign to `_vimrc`:

```
map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

If I open gvim and then press F2 NERDTree will open but in the directory `Windows/system32` which takes a long time to cache.

Can I change the setting so that it opens in `M:\`. I've used `help: NERDTreeToggle` and from the help I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
:NERDTreeToggle M:\
```

Maybe I need another setting so that only on start-up NERDTree will automatically start and be visible and open at `M:\` - is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, NERDTree starts in the current working directory. You've probably started Vim through the installed Start Menu shortcut, which defaults to the `system32` directory. (You can check from inside Vim with `:pwd`.)

I would recommend that you modify the shortcut that starts GVIM (`gvim.lnk`: right mouse button > Properties > Start in:) to start in `M:\`. That's probably a better default for starting Vim, and it also solves the NERDTree problem.

Comment: +1 perfect Ingo. Was thinking of you yesterday - now I am 1wk into the vim experiment (addiction) I remembered you mentioned working on SO posts using vim ....how do you do that? and why is it quicker? do you write them in vim and then copy them across to here?

Comment: Various plugins integrate an external editor (for text areas) into the browser. I use Firefox + Pentadactyl; I've described the exact setup in a [blog post](http://ingo-karkat.de/blog/2012/05/22/Pentadactyl%20set%20filetype%20in%20external%20Vim%20editor%20based%20on%20URL.html).